# Pointer being reallocated wasn't allocated

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I want to make a function which separates a given string according to delimiter (winter-is-coming -> winter|is|coming) to its sub strings and returning a null string at the end of the double character pointer. When I run this code under mac os x in C90 standard, I get the first string as "winter" (~as w, wi, win, wint, winte, winter~ when I print temp in the loop) but then it suddenly crushes and gives this error:

```
untitled2(30275,0x109cf25c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fec9a400630: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
untitled2(30275,0x109cf25c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** split(char *str, char delimeter) {
  int i = 0;
  int c = 0;
  int k = 1;
  char **result;
  result = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*));
  *result = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
  char * temp;
  temp = *result;
  while (str[i] != '\0') {

    if (str[i] != delimeter) {
      *(temp + i) = *(str + i);
      i++;
      temp = (char *) realloc(*(result + c), sizeof(char) * (i + 1));
      continue;
    }

    else {
      c++;
      k++;
      result = (char **) realloc(result, sizeof(char *) * k);

      *(result + c) = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
      i++;
      *(temp + i) = '\0';

    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", result[0]);
  return result;
}

int main() {
  char *cpr;
  cpr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen("winter-is-coming"));
  strcpy(cpr, "winter-is-coming");
  printf("%s\n", split(cpr, '-')[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only `realloc` a pointer that was not allocated if it is `NULL`. Some system will zero a memory allocation but that is not defined by the C standard. It is a bad idea to pass an uninitialised pointer to `realloc`. But things go wrong even before then with `*(temp+i)=*(str+i);` which derefences an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: But I already initially allocated the pointer(result) which I want to reallocate at the start of the code.

Comment: It is allocated for c=0 already other than that I allocate it when I need it in the else statement.

Comment: You allocated a double pointer, but not any offset you subsequently dereference.

Comment: *(result + c) = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)); isn't this line doing that allocation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insufficient allocation - by 1.

A *string* of length `N` needs `N+1` `char`.  Cast not needed in C.

```
// cpr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen("winter-is-coming"));
cpr = malloc(strlen("winter-is-coming") + 1);
// Robust code would check for allocation success
if (cpr == NULL) {
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
strcpy(cpr,"winter-is-coming");
```

---

Code can fail to return a good indication of the number of splits from `split()`.  Consider `char ** split("", .-)` for example.  Also then `printf("%s\n",result[0]);` is UB.

---

Other problems may exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, test data ensures that there will be at least one delimeter and only one character for the delimeter..

Answer (score 0):

Just from a first look I am suspicious of

```
result = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

I think you should have something like

```
result = (char **)malloc(MAX_NUMBER_OF_DIFFERENT_SUBSTRINGS * sizeof(char*));
```

does that make sense?

otherwise

```
 *(result +c)
```

does not make sense....

so try increasing the memory allocated to result....

but this is probably only part of the story

Comment: It is reasonable but I don't have the max number of substrings

Comment: just throw in a large number and see if it helps.. ... sorry just a suggestion to try to get things working...

Comment: The whole point of this code is to work with a dynamic array, thanks anyway

Comment: @Crazy_39365 Ok, - I was partly suggesting adding a number to see if that would solve the problem- or if the problem was elsewhere, but I see what you mean about working with a dynamic array.